# How to prepare variables with mild skew for multiple regression?

Tags: normal-distribution, multiple-regression, data-transformation, skewness

I am doing some univariate analysis on a variable before doing regression.  I think it is very skewed.
Three histograms are of (1) the original variable; (2) log10 transformation, and (3) inverse of the data to the power of 4.5.

**How should the variable be prepared for regression?**

[image]

Comment: Why are you transforming the data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no requirement that this data be normal for regression, only the residuals of the model.  So, do your regression and check the residuals and then see if you need to transform anything.

Answer (score 5):

Your original data looks fine. I've seen datasets where the skew was far more extreme than that. Do your regression and check the diagnostics (in particular, see if your estimated trend makes sense and there is no strong evidence of non-additivity) before making any transformations.

Comment: If the lm residuals don't work out a glm with a Poisson distribution will likely do the trick (for the original data)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a transformation of the data, you might want to consider the [Box-Cox transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box.E2.80.93Cox_transformation) which is reviewed in [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2348250).